# ASP.NET Core Deserializing From Body, w/ Default Values

Tags: asp.net-core, json.net, deserialization, asp.net-core-webapi

I have the following controller (abbreviated):

```
public class ServicesController : Controller
{
    private readonly IServiceRepository _repo;
    public ServicesController(IServiceRepository repo)
    {
        _repo = repo;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<StatusCodeResult> CreateService([FromBody] JsonServiceEntity service)
    {
        return await _repo.CreateServiceAsync(new ServiceEntity(service));
    }
}
```

The JsonServiceEntity class looks like this (abbreviated):

```
public class JsonServiceEntity
{
    public string Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
}
```

`Id` is a string in the form of a guid. If one is passed in from the client, I should use the given Id. If no value is passed in from the client, I should generate a new guid and use that.

However, I can't get it to use the default value when none is given from the client. No matter what, it ends up as an empty string. I can debug and watch it hit the property and generate a new guid for the default, which is promptly overwritten by a call to the setter with an empty string.

I've tried different values of `NullValueHandling` and `DefaultValueHandling` on the `SerializerSettings` in my `Startup.cs`, but that hasn't helped. If I set `[Required]` on the `Id` property, I get a ModelState error letting me know that the attempted value was `null`, not an empty string.

How do I get it to take the default value?

```
CONNECTServiceRegistry.dll!CONNECTServiceRegistry.Models.JsonServiceEntity.Id.set(string value) Line 45 C#
Newtonsoft.Json.dll!Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.ExpressionValueProvider.SetValue(object target, object value) Unknown
Newtonsoft.Json.dll!Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.SetPropertyValue(Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty property, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter propertyConverter, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContainerContract containerContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty containerProperty, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, object target)    Unknown
Newtonsoft.Json.dll!Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(object newObject, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonObjectContract contract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty member, string id) Unknown
Newtonsoft.Json.dll!Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract contract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty member, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContainerContract containerContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty containerMember, object existingValue) Unknown
Newtonsoft.Json.dll!Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract contract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty member, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContainerContract containerContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty containerMember, object existingValue)  Unknown
Newtonsoft.Json.dll!Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, bool checkAdditionalContent)  Unknown
Newtonsoft.Json.dll!Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType)   Unknown
Newtonsoft.Json.dll!Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType)   Unknown
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.JsonInputFormatter.ReadRequestBodyAsync(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.InputFormatterContext context, System.Text.Encoding encoding) Line 303 C#
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.TextInputFormatter.ReadRequestBodyAsync(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.InputFormatterContext context) Line 57    C#
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.InputFormatter.ReadAsync(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.InputFormatterContext context) Line 116  C#
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.BodyModelBinder.BindModelAsync(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ModelBindingContext bindingContext) Line 158   C#
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ParameterBinder.BindModelAsync(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionContext actionContext, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.IModelBinder modelBinder, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.IValueProvider valueProvider, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions.ParameterDescriptor parameter, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ModelMetadata metadata, object value) Line 239  C#
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerBinderDelegateProvider.CreateBinderDelegate.__Bind|0(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ControllerContext controllerContext, object controller, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object> arguments) Line 77    C#
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.BindArgumentsAsync() Line 424   C#
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(ref Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.State next, ref Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted) Line 69   C#
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync() Line 385   C#
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.State next, ref Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted) Line 692  C#
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter() Line 793 C#
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.State next, ref Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted) Line 407  C#
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync() Line 123    C#
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync() Line 81   C#
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.MvcAttributeRouteHandler.RouteAsync.AnonymousMethod__0(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext c) Line 105    C#
```

Comment: Are you using asp.net core 2.1?

Comment: Not an informative one. I can't get Visual Studio to show the call to Guid.NewGuid() in the trace. However, I can put a breakpoint on the default and the setter, see that the default is called, then the setter. When the setter is called, the Id property has a valid guid value. I've added the trace anyway.

Comment: Yes, this is asp.net core 2.1.

Comment: Does your client actually pass the `Id: ""` in the JSON text?

Comment: Can't reproduce it, no matter what I try. Perhaps you should look at the client. Seems that Id is always set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the client actually passes an empty string as the `Id`, you can instruct Json.Net to handle an empty string as a default value using the `DefaultValue` attribute:

```
public class JsonServiceEntity
{
    [DefaultValue("")]
    public string Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
}
```

Then in JSON configuration, set it to `Ignore` default values:

```
DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore
```

See [Documentation](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DefaultValueAttributeIgnore.htm)

Comment: This is perfect for my situation, and works great. Thanks!

Comment: You should also add `NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore` to handle the `null` case.

Answer (score 3):

When you specify a default on an auto-implemented property like:

```
public string Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
```

The default will only be used if the value is not set at all. Here, If the id is not being set by the client, then it should not sent at all, i.e.:

If this is your current JSON:

```
{
    "id": "",
    "name": "foo"
}
```

Then what the client should be sending is:

```
{
    "name": "foo"
}
```

Then, your default will then be utilized as you're wanting. If you cannot achieve this, or you simply want to handle the case of the client sending an empty string incorrectly, then you'll need a custom getter and setter:

```
private string id;
public string Id
{
    get => id;
    set => id = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value) ? Guid.NewGuid().ToString() : value;
}
```

Comment: Passing "id": null will cause the value to be null, not NewGuid.  So, it has to be omitted.

Comment: It will generate a new guid every time Id get accessed.

Comment: Yeah, If you moved the call to Guid.NewGuid to the *setter* instead, this would work well (or changed the value of `id` in the getter). However, I liked the selected solution better because it fits my usecase well and is a bit more elegant.